# How to send values of the select box to servlet using ajax or jquery?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

Im new to ajax. I want to redirect to servlet with the parameter value of the select box to my servlet. This is my code and its not retrieving values when I use request.getParameter("type") it gives me a null.

```
     <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {       
         $('#type').change(function() {                              
           $.get('pickasset', function(responseJson) {
             var type = $('#type').val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: 'PickAssetServlet',
                data: type          
            }); 
           });
        });
      });
    </script>

    <form action="pickasset" method="post">
        <select id="type" name="type">
           <option value="Non-Sap">Non Sap</option>
           <option value="Sap">Sap</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

When i change the select box, it must go to servlet and do logic there.

Answer (score 0):

send your data like this-

```
data: { type : type }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting the selected option from the select field, you need to use 
`$('#type').find(":selected").text()` to retrieve the selected option. `val()` doesn't work with select fields. Also do what pXL said because that's how you send data with jQuery ajax methods

Comment: i just want the parameter of select box to be available to my servlet. I want to get the parameter of the select box which is "type" like request.getParameter("type");

Answer (score 0):

Check box value must be obtained from checkbox in the right way, as mentioned in jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/val/), just pay attention to multiple select, you're gonna have an array of values. You are doing it right, according to docs.

```
var varValue = var type = $('#type').val();
```

Then sending data as 'json' you will be able to read them with request.getParameter('type')

```
data: { "type" : varValue }
```

If you still get null, try to check if your "type" param and his value are in the request (chrome request inspector will be usefull, then check it in the debugger).

.

P.S.

Just check if you have something in your webapp filterchain that may wrap you request or hide some params, in some large web-app you get lost very easly.